# Can you pull data from two seperate tables located in a single result set? [NOT JOIN QUESTION]

Tags: php, mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to write a code that generates two SEPARATE temp. tables that have nothing to join on (hence no join) but use the same data in a single stored procedure to be generated, but I'm not sure how to access the second table with PHP? If at all? Usually I would be working with a single table from a single result set.

Does the second table exist in the result set? Or do I HAVE to run a second procedure to generate the second table?

When I dump the contents of my result set I only get first table's data.

Edit: Help would be appreciated cleaning up this question. Thank you.

Comment: You need to run two queries, if these are independent.

Comment: Some databases allow a single procedure to return multiple "result sets" (e.g. Oracle, PostgreSQL). Unfortunately this is not the case in MySQL. You'll need two procedures.

Comment: Ah I see. What a shame, thanks @TheImpaler . If you submit the comment as an answer I'll mark it as a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some databases allow a single procedure to return multiple "result sets" (e.g. Oracle, PostgreSQL).

Unfortunately this is not the case in MySQL. You'll need two procedures.